# angular 6 show loading image until image read from api is completely loaded

Tags: angular, image, loading

In an angular 6 application, i call a service to load the images from an api. The image sizes are very big and they take some time to load, while they are loading, i  want to show a placeholder gif, and show the image once it is completely loaded.
I am new to angular and any suggestion to fix this would be of great help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code to show how you're loading the images?

Comment: `<div *ngFor="let product of products">  <img src="{{product['product'].image}}" alt="">  </div>`

Comment: Please edit the question to include it in the question. Also, you mention you're loading the images from an API, that's what I wanted to see, not an `*ngFor` loop.

Comment: It is a webservice containing json array of objects, it contains information about the products title, description, price and thumbnail image of the product. I want to show all those products list. but the image is loading slowly. I want to show a loading gif and then show image once the image is completely loaded..